# bindParam doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, bind, param

I'm moving from MYSQL to PDO. I read the PDO official documentation, but I cannot find the fail on the code.

```
$name = 'fooUser';
$stmt = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:name');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->execute();
```

This query return me the affected rows, and it shouldn't happen.

Comment: `PDO::PARAM_INT` is used to force PDO to parse the input as an integer. `fooUser` is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_INT );
```

To

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

you are setting the wrong kind of input!

Comment: But this is the problem, the query will be return an error because in bindParam() I need an INT ..?

Comment: @mauriblint well then stop sending it a string? Basically, if you want to get the username, which is stored in the database as a string, you need to tell PDO that you're sending it a string (well, you can do) - so whats the problem?